# At the end of Revenge of the Sith, are the suns rising or setting?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

I always assumed that they were setting, for the symbolism of the twins (Luke and Leia) dropping off the map for a while, but I've heard people say they're rising, as kind of a reverse bookend for the setting suns scene in the original movie. Anyone know the official answer?

[image]

Comment: Ash the soundtrack of that scene is named "Binary Sunset", I may assume that they're setting.

Comment: You're thinking of the scene from the original movie--the relevant track listing for Revenge of the Sith is "A New Hope and End Credits".

Comment: One is rising and one is setting..

Comment: @SachinShekhar - The script (and book) say otherwise

Comment: @Richard  ..not to mention, common sense.  The rising/setting of a star is determined by the direction of rotation of the *planet or satellite where the observer is located*, as opposed to movement of the star(s) as such.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nope. The Force is strong on Tatoonie which screwed Spacetime curvature such that it can happen.. :)

Comment: I'd actually throw it out there that it could be both.  The suns could be setting on the age of the Jedi, but also rising on Luke and Leia's arrival, signaling the beginning of a new Jedi age.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Per the [shooting](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html) script;

> **240 EXT. TATOOINE-SUNSET**
>
> OBI-WAN rides up to the moisture farm homestead on an EOPIE. He
>   dismounts, takes the BABY out of a papoose on his back, and walks
>   toward AUNT BERU, who walks over to greet him. They talk for a moment,
>   and OBI-WAN turns the baby over to the young homesteader. AUNT BERU
>   walks to UNCLE OWEN who is standing on the ridge near the homestead.
>   OBI-WAN leaves as **OWEN, BERU, and the BABY watch the twin suns set**.

and the [novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III%3a_Revenge_of_the_Sith_%28novel%29);

> And on Tatooine, a Jedi Master brings an infant boy to the homestead
>   of Owen and Beru Lars— Then he rides his eopie off into the Jundland
>   Wastes, **toward the setting suns**.

Answer (score 7):

The suns cannot rise and set from the same direction. Arguably, the direction of sight is the same as in A New Hope. The suns are setting.

Comment: Arguably, it's not physically impossible for the suns to be moving in opposite directions, retrograde to the planet. Just very very unlikely; http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/06/Twinsun_vectors.jpg/300px-Twinsun_vectors.jpg